# Java: How do I save seperate lines of text to a string array from a .txt file?

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, object

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class readFiles2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("someFile.txt"));

    try{
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        String readStringLine = reader.readLine();
        String[] lines= {};


        for(int i = 0; readStringLine != null; i++){
            readStringLine = reader.readLine();

            //Trying to save seperate lines of text in an array.
            lines[i] = readStringLine.toString();
        }

    }
    finally{
        reader.close();
    }


}
```

So what I'm trying to do is save separate lines of strings from a .txt file to a `String[]` array. I'm kind of at a loss right now and don't really know what else I can do.

Comment: Use a `BufferedWriter`, calling `append` to write the text and `newLine` to add a new line when you're done (for each line)

Comment: Is your code not working? A problem i see is that your array is never given a size so when you call lines[i] it will crash

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know how many strings there are for your array, you might want to put the strings in a list and convert to an array at the end:

```
String readStringLine;
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

while((readStringLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(readStringLine);
}

String[] linesArray = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
```

**Edit:** Simpified to use a while loop to gather the line from the reader.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList<>();
    FileReader file = new FileReader(file.txt);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
    while (reader.ready()) {
       line.add(reader.readLine());
       reader.close();
       file.close();
}`

To acess, use line.get(i); where i>=0 and i<=array.size

Answer (score 0):

Using autocloseable interface and Java 8 streams:

```
String [] stringsArray = null;
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("someFile.txt"))) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    br.lines().forEach(c -> strings.add(c));
    stringsArray = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
}
```

*You need Java 8  to run this code*